# Return an Azure Table entity; better to use a DTO or Deconstructing a tuple?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

Reading up on [deconstructing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) I've noticed you can pull out select properties from an object into a tuple. This seems to be a great way to return a subset of objects from an Azure Table query which would otherwise populate your query object with properties you might not need (i.e. eTag, PartitionKey, RowKey, etc.).

In the past I've created my class and within it I create a DTO to represent the sub-set of properties I want to return from a web API query as such:

```
public class Person : TableEntity
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
            PartitionKey = firstName;
            RowKey = lastName;
    }

    public Person(){} //parameterless constructor needed by Azure Tables

    public string SomeValue1 {get; set;}
    public string SomeValue2 {get; set;}
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public string SomeValue1 {get; set;}
    public string SomeValue2 {get; set;}
}
```

When I use my `Person` object I'm thinking I could create an extension method which returns the tuple and get rid of `PersonDTO` altogether. Does this make sense? Is it a viable alternative to defining a DTO and if not, what are the consequences? I'm not a fan of having to manage a separate class for the DTO which is really just a sub-set of properties from the original entity in Azure Tables.

```
public static (string, string) GetValues(this Person p)
{
    return (p.SomeValue1, p.SomeValue2);
}
```

Called as such:

```
Person person = new Person("Frank", "Rizzo")
{
    person.SomeValue1 = "Value1",
    person.SomeValue2 = "Value2"
};
var (personValue1, personValue2) = person.GetValues();
```

**Update:** An alternative appears to use overloads with the `Deconstruct` name without the need for an extension method as follows:

```
public void Deconstruct(out someValue1, out someValue2)
{
    someValue1 = SomeValue1;
    someValue2 = SomeValue2;
}
```

Called as such:

```
Person p = new Person("Frank", "Rizzo")
{
    SomeValue1 = "Value1",
    SomeValue2 = "Value2"
};

var (someValue1, someValue2) = p;
```

Syntax could be slightly off above (writing this from memory and not an actual working code sample).

Comment: So it appears like the main goal is to get rid of the meta-data fields that Table Storage adds? Or do you strictly only want to return a couple of the properties?

Comment: In some cases it could be getting rid of meta-data fields. In other cases it would be necessary to be very selective in what gets returned.

Comment: Have you ever looked into [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)?

Comment: Briefly. I guess I'm just trying to understand if this is a viable alternative and what the pros/cons might be as opposed to a solution involving another dependency.

Comment: The tuple approach doesn’t really have any cons (aside from being structs) when it’s just a tuple with two or three tuple elements. For much more elements they get inefficient due to their value semantics.